# Do I want to overfit, when doing outlier detection based on regression?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, outliers, overfitting, anomaly-detection

Imagine, we have speed data of car and we would like to detect, if car speeds up or down more than it should.

Do I want to just overfit my model, so the outlier (higher or lower speed) would lead me to higher residual easing the process of outlier detection?

Edit: To clarify, training data have no outliers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I want to just overfit my model, so the outlier (higher or lower speed) would lead me to higher residual easing the process of outlier detection?

No, you don't. A heavily overfitted model would perfectly fit your data, but not generalize outside it. So it can be the case that it would consider as an outlier anything that is not alike to your training data. For an overfitted model to work for outlier detection, your training data would need to contain *every possible scenario* to be observed in the real world. But, if you had data on every possible scenario, you wouldn't need a machine learning model, since you could simply search your database and if the datapoint is not found among the "valid" cases, it is an anomaly. Most likely, your data does not contain every possible scenario, especially since speed is a real number so there is an infinite number of them. That is why you need a model that is able to fill in the gaps, so it *needs* to generalize outside of the training data.

Comment: I see, so a case where we want to overfit in purpose, is kind of against the nature of the use case. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to detect "if car speeds up or down **more than it should**", then your regression model should capture the kinds of acceleration the car "should" be performing, but not capture the kinds it "shouldn't". If your model is very over-fit, it will capture all kinds of acceleration, and nothing will be an outlier. If it's under-fit, it won't capture some acceleration that you think of as normal, so will show too many outliers.

All that aside, linear regression on it's own is not generally appropriate for time series data, and not necessarily the best way of identifying outliers in any kind of data. There are specific approaches for identifying outliers in time series data you should look into.

Comment: "it will capture all kinds of acceleration, and nothing will be an outlier." However the training data only have **allowed accelerations**, so is this still apply? Then If I overfit, I would learn the allowed accelerations really well no?

Comment: The details in your comment completely change the scope of your question, so I suggest you go back and provide more details in the question. What you're describing is a case of [one-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification).

Comment: Hi Eoin, I've realized after your answer, so I've already edited the question.